# spinner or loader while fragment page get completedly loaded

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-spinner, android-loader

I have created an android application using Android Fragments as described in [Dynamically Prevent Rotation On Android Fragment](http://www.peteonsoftware.com/index.php/2014/03/07/dynamically-preventing-rotation-on-an-android-fragment/).

The application is working fine but the problem is that say a particular fragment say Photo Gallery might calls several http calls and might certain time for bringing all the images. So when we click the Photo Gallery it seems stuck for sometime.

How can we show some slider or progress bar like something till the fragment view get loaded completely?

An example like is as shown below:

[image]

My `PhotoGalleryFragment` is given below

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PhotoGalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    public PhotoGalleryFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo_gallery, container, false);

        // some http calls to be triggered

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html), for example:

```
public class PhotoGalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo_gallery, container, false);

        // some http calls to be triggered

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "", "Loading...", true, false);
    }
}
```

When you http calls are ended you can dismiss the `ProgressDialog` with `mProgressDialog.dismiss()`.

Comment: what is the use of `onAttach` function

Comment: `onAttach` is called when a `Fragment` is first attached to its `Activity`

Comment: do we have any other function like that to identify when the `Fragment` view is completely loaded

Comment: What do you mean with completely loaded? If you mean after the http calls  are ended the answer is no. You need to check when the http calls return, fill the data of your `Fragment` and in that moment dismiss the dialog